# Delphi Web Service parâmetros

Tags: json, delphi, web-service, datasnap

Tenho um serviço rodando em Delphi com DataSnap REST, ele serve para leitura de dados e retorna a consulta para quem requisitou, mas agora o cliente precisa consumir esses dados via web passando alguns parâmetros, até ai beleza, fiz a função ele retorna os dados em um array de JSON, minha dúvida seria como tratar os parâmetros que ele passa, como por exemplo

> /?reference=BUTTON&type=raw_material&uid=BTN-1234

passando um parâmetro reference= no DataSnap REST seria assim

/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/funcao/parametro

não tem a necessidade de especificar o que vais pesquisar, com um sinal de igual somente passar os parâmetros, alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema usando a função `GetInvocationMetaData`, a onde ele me retorna os parâmetros usados no link para o `WebService`. Vou colocar um exemplo de como usar essa função:

declarar no usues `Data.DBXPlatform`

```
var  
  oMetaData: TDSInvocationMetadata  
  i: Integer;  
  s: String;  
begin  
  oMetaData: GetInvocationMetadata;

  for i := 0 to oMetaData.QueryParams.Count-1 do
  begin
    s := oMetaData.QueryParams[i];
  end;
```